# Query that formats the data into new columns based on the value of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

A table in a database has the following data:

| index | item | height | width |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 5 | 1 |
| 1 | A | 6 | 1 |
| 2 | A | 7 | 1 |
| 0 | B | 55 | 8 |
| 1 | B | 66 | 8 |
| 2 | B | 77 | 8 |

With an SQL query it should be turned into:

| index | A.height | A.width | B.height | B.width |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 5 | 1 | 55 | 8 |
| 1 | 6 | 1 | 66 | 8 |
| 2 | 7 | 1 | 77 | 8 |

There can be, at the time of writing the SQL query, an unknown number of different `item`s (A,B,C,D,...), and the new columns should be generated accordingly (... D.height, D.width ...).

What would be the best approach to do this in SQL?

The goal is to

- have a continuous `index` column without duplicates, and
- query a slice of the data by using the `index` (e.g. WHERE index BETWEEN 1 AND 6), and
- have all the data returned with one query
- (and, of course, not modify the original table)

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @DaleK Not much yet. I'm not quite sure where to start, or whether this is an easy task or so difficult I should try some completely different approach first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is a Dynamic PIVOT which requires Dynamic SQL.

There are many examples, but I get the sense you need a nudge.

**Example**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select *
 From  (
        select [Index]
               ,B.*
         From  yourtable A
         Cross Apply ( values ( concat(item,''.height''),height)
                             ,( concat(item,''.width'' ),width )
                      )B(Item,Value)
       ) src
 Pivot ( max(value) for Item in (' + stuff((select Distinct ',' + QuoteName(concat(item,'.height'))+',' + QuoteName(concat(item,'.width')) From  yourtable Order By 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') + ') ) pvt
'
Exec(@SQL)
```

**Results**

[image]

**EDIT:  The Generated SQL Looks like this**

```
Select *
 From  (
        select [Index]
               ,B.*
         From  yourtable A
         Cross Apply ( values ( concat(item,'.height'),height)
                             ,( concat(item,'.width' ),width )
                      )B(Item,Value)
       ) src
 Pivot ( max(value) for Item in ([A.height],[A.width],[B.height],[B.width]) ) pvt
```

Comment: how to write in postgresql. Can you please help me on this

Comment: @LearnHadoop  I'm got a postgresql guy.

Comment: In the example, what is `B` and `A` (in `B.*`, `yourtable A`, ...) ?

In other words, does this query work without modifications if the `item` column would contain only values `C` and `D` for instance?

Comment: Assuming that `yourtable` is the name of the table, I get an error `Incorrect syntax near 'For'`, and if I remove the `Order By 1 For XML Path('')` I get another error: `Subquery returned more than 1 value`.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without Dynamic SQL?

Comment: @hyttysmyrkky SQL Server is declarative by design.  You would need to know all the required columns

Comment: @hyttysmyrkky Take a look at the EDIT.  It now contains the generated SQL

Comment: @JohnCappelletti So if I understood correctly, `A` and `B` in the Example are `item`s, and what I'm trying to do is not possible in SQL, except maybe by using Dynamic SQL, if you're able to somehow read all the possible values in the `item` column first and use those in the names of the new columns, which is something your Example doesn't do? If that's correct, I think the best way then is to write an external program that makes multiple queries and parses the data into the target format. (Also in that case I'll mark your answer as accepted because it's probably the best you can do in SQL.)

Comment: @hyttysmyrkky You are correct.  This is not possible without dynamic SQL.  There is no Excel Pivot or Access Cross Tab functions available,  as I mentioned before, SQL Server is declarative by design.  You could take the second (generated) query and expand as necessary but you will always be chasing that as new items are added.

The dynamic sql provided is rather concise.   I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Ok sorry I misunderstood. So the Example query (with Dynamic SQL) does work without modifications(chasing, inputting 'C' and 'D') even if the `item` column would contain only for example values 'C' and 'D', and not 'A' /'B'(?) Then that's great! In my case I got some errors though, but I also have a very limited access to the db in question, so the errors could be related to that. I'll have to study the Dynamic SQL and the Example a bit more.